# Accessing an instance from outside the file

Tags: ruby, class, object, import, require

I have three files as follows:

- `database.rb` - Represents a database
- `log.rb` - Logs things that happen in the database
- `main.rb` - A driver program that takes in user input and calls functions from the other files

### database.rb

```
class Database
  def initialize()
      @data = Hash.new
      @modified_recently = false
  end

  def build_db
    # Reads CSV file into program
  end
end
```

### main.rb

```
require_relative "./database"
require_relative "./log"

db = Database.new # Create a new database
log = Log.new # Create a new log
db.build_db # Build the database from a file
```

The problem is that I need the log to be able to access the database. However, I am creating the object in `main.rb` (which requires `log.rb` so therefore I cannot also require it from there). Have I set this up completely wrong? How can I:

1. Have `main` send commands to both `database` and `log`
2. Have `database` store data
3. Have `log` be able to get what's happening in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, just pass an instance of `Database` to `Log`’s constructor:

```
class Log
  def initialize db
    @db = db
  end
  ...
end
```

in `main.rb`:

```
db = Database.new # Create a new database
log = Log.new db  # Create a new log
```

Comment: Ah; I didn't realize they could just be passed like that. Thank you!

Comment: Everyhing is an object in ruby, so if you can give an Integer as and argument, you can also give an instance of any object you have created yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you want to be able to run your database.rb independently from your main, eg for testing you can also check if the log is already defined by the main.rb

```
#database.rb
require_relative "./log" #is only going to be required once
db = Database.new
log = Log.new unless defined? log
```